# How to implement Kafka @RetryableTopic using Spring cloud stream kafka?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

blocking kafka retry using @Retryable topic implementation on with spring-kafka.

Would like to ask for implementations using the same with `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka`.

I noticed the kafka binder retry is working but it doesn't introduce the delay that is intended.

Answer (score 0):

The binder does not support the non-blocking topic retry mechanism; it is only supported by `@KafkaListener`.

Comment: Can this be achieved with any other mechanism like ErrorHandler or RetryTemplate?